# Perl Win32::API() call() function

Tags: perl

Dear all,
I am trying to get the value of char pointer or string in the return of call() function for my dll.
my dll is having a function RandomDec(long , int*) and returns a string. so what will be my call using Win32::API(). I have tried this and didn't succeed. plz help

```
use Win32::API;  
my @lpBuffer = " " x 20;   
my $pp= \@lpBuffer;  
my $xy=0;  
my $ff= \$xy;  
my $fun2 = new Win32::API('my.dll','RandomDec','NP','**P**')or die $^E;  
$pp = $fun2->Call(4,$ff);
```

how to get using $pp ?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple errors in your code.

1. `my @lpBuffer = " " x 20; my $pp= \@lpBuffer;`

=>  `my $pp = " " x 20;`

You are mixing arrays with strings, and you don't need a perl ref for a c ptr.
Similar for the int*.

1. N is for number not long. L would be unsigned, you need signed, so l.

```
    use Win32::API;
    my $pp = " " x 20;   # alloc a string
    my $xy = 0;          # alloc an int
    my $fun2 = new Win32::API('my.dll','RandomDec','lP','P') or die $^E;  
    $pp = $fun2->Call(4,$xy);
```

I haven't check if Win32::API can do lvalue assignment to char*. Normally not, so $pp will be a foreign pointer to some string after the call, and the prev. PV slot for $pp will be lost, and inaccessible from perl.
With FFI's and the WinAPI also you usually return int, not strings. 
Strings only via sideeffects, as function arg.

Comment: Thanks a lot! but how can i get strings as return type from a dll function. please help me. i can't find any solution.

Comment: You have to know how creates your string first. You in perl or your DLL? You get back a pointer from the dll, and this is the string. In my fixed example $pp is the string allocated by perl and probably changed by your dll.